# Как выполнить sql функцию из bat файла?

Tags: sql, postgresql, bat

Всем привет. Как написать батник, который выполнит sql функцию `update_center`, которая внутри бд лежит в Schemas/test_work/Functions? Использую субд postresql.

Функция чисто для примера пусть будет такой:

```sql
create function test_work.update_center()
returns bigint
language plpgsql
as
$$
begin
    insert into data.quality_control_defect_temp (id, weld_qc_method_id, defect_id, description, depth, length, coordinates)
    values (4, 12, 1000, 'D=0.5', null, null, '500') returning id;
end;
$$;
```

Пробовал следующим образом:

```
psql postgresql://*:*@localhost:5432/password -c "select * from update_center();"
```

До флага `-c` пытаюсь подключиться к бд, а после - выполнить функцию. Но это не работает:

```
psql: предупреждение: лишний аргумент "select * from update_center();" проигнорирован
```

Что делаю не так?

Comment: Функция возвращает BIGINT - а Вы её используете так, словно она возвращает таблицу... попробуйте `SELECT update_center() FROM DUAL;`

Comment: @Akina, пишет ОШИБКА: отношение "dual" не существует

Comment: Преобразуйте функцию в процедуру. И просто CALL, EXECUTE, или что там в постгрессе.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте поменять местами параметр с запросом и URI базы.

```
psql -c "select * from update_center();" postgresql://*:*@localhost:5432/password
```

По [этой доке](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/app-psql.html) опшензы идут сначала, а описание базы вконце.

P. S. - И исправьте сам запрос как советует [@Akina](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/229437/akina)

Comment: Alexey R, выдаёт ошибку: отношение "dual" не существует

Comment: тогда `select update_center();` либо `select test_work.update_center();`. Подробнее [здесь](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/sql-syntax-calling-funcs.html).

Comment: Alexey R, `SELECT migration_work.update_center()` без DUAL выдаёт: `Ошибка: в запросе нет назначения для данных результата. Контекст: функция PL/pgSQL migration_work.update_center(), строка 3, оператор SQL-оператор`

Comment: Скорее всего проблема в функции. Попробуйте отладить все не через командную строку а в какой-нибудь более дружелюбной среде..